# Are operators faster than functions?

Tags: c++, performance

While searching for the difference in `new` and `malloc`, I came across this statement ([source](https://www.includehelp.com/cpp-tutorial/difference-between-new-and-malloc.aspx)):

> new is faster than malloc() because an operator is always faster than a function.

Are operators always faster than functions? If so, why? I would really appreciate low-level explanations (you can assume basic compiler, SASS, and hardware knowledge).

Comment: Many implementations have `new` calling `malloc()` internally.  No one at that site stated that little fact?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no fundamental difference between operator and function. I think people just call lower-level and more fundamental functions as operators, in which it is obviously true that lower-level functions run faster

Comment: `includehelp.com` just became another "be careful what you read on the internet" type site. Stick with recognized and peer-reviewed (or primary) authorities. If there is any question which is faster, dump the assembly and look.

Comment: With operator overloading I can have an operator call multiple functions, which by necessity makes the operator take longer than any function it calls, proving that statement false. I can probably also create a function that is optimised to zero instructions, thus being faster than even an operator that gets translated to a single assembly instruction.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, exactly. There are sites which one can trust (like cppreference), and some sites which post crap on a regular basis (like this one, geeksforgeeks, etc.)

Comment: *"operator is always faster than a function"* is just nonsense - especially so in C++ where invoking an operator is often just a syntactic sugar over calling a function.

Comment: As far as I know, `malloc` allocates memory and does very little more; `new` does that too, and also executes a constructor *which can take an arbitrarily long time to run.* I don't have much confidence in that site.

Comment: Think about the assembly. In the final compiled code the work either needs to be done where it is needed or by jumping to another area of instructions. Some functions may end up being copied into their call site via inlining, but both operators and plain functions are candidates for this process

Comment: Looking at that site, it has multiple contributors, and no one tapped someone on the shoulder to say "that doesn't make sense"?  That shows they don't even peer-review themselves.

Comment: operators *are* functions.

Comment: *Built-in* operators are not functions, with the *exception* of `new` and `delete`, but all overriden operators are functions. The statement is complete nonsense.

Comment: For functions the compiler will build a stack frame call the function then dispose of the stack frame and return the result. Operators are generally compiled in-line, especially simple operators like "a + b", but depending on the library operators may call function/s. I hope that helps.

Comment: @dyukha even GeeksforGeeks? Then what are trustworthy sources other than cppreference.com?

Comment: For any language and library their docs and source code are trustworthy. Everything else is trustworthy as long as it references them, performs reasonably good experiments or analyzes byte-code (or similar). When I see questionable statements like what you've seen, I check docs, look for measurements or perform them myself. This particular statement was a pure crap, so I didn't even bother to do any of this. For question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246038/initialize-array-of-custom-type-constructor (see the first version) I first checked the docs to see whether the statement is true.

Comment: @AgnosticCucumber -- The GeeksforGeeks site *may* have some good analysis of how to solve a problem.  The issue is that the C++ implementation to solve those problems that's posted there is anywhere from mediocre to absolutely horrible in terms of C++.  Memory leaks, usage of variable length arrays (which is not standard C++), using `vector` and VLA's in the same program (indicating the author has no idea what a vector is to be used for), etc.

Answer (score 5):

> > new is faster than malloc() because an operator is always faster than a function.

This is completely untrue. In fact, it is quite typical that the default behaviour of new expression is to internally call `malloc`, in which case it cannot possibly be faster.

There is no reason to expect different performance for using one over another as long as the contending programs do the same thing. The reasons to use `new` instead of `malloc` are not related to performance.

> Are operators faster than functions?

Calling a function at runtime is potentially slower than not calling a function.

But, as we've found out, an operator can actually internally call a function. Besides, a function call for the abstract machine doesn't necessarily mean that a function will be called at runtime. As long as the compiler is able to produce the result of the function at compile time, or if it is able to expand the call inline, then there is no need for any function call overhead.

So, it depends on what function calls we are discussing. As far as a C++ function call is concerned: It is not necessarily slower than the use of an operator.

Also, do note that all overloaded operators that operate on class types are actually function calls to the operator overload function.