# Initialize array of custom type constructor

Tags: c++

I'm having difficulties in declarations and initialization of an array with custom types.

I want the declarations and initialization of an array with a **custom datatype**.

My custom datatype looks like this:

```
struct Node
{
    long long data;
    int count;
    std::string name;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(long long data, int count, std::string name): data(data), count(count), name(name), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};
```

Now I'm trying couple of things here which are not working.

```
Node nodes[100] = {Node(0,0,"unknown")};
```

Or,

```
Node nodes[100](Node(0,0,"unknown"));
```

Or,

```
Node nodes[100]{Node(0,0,"unknown")};
```

Can anyone help me with this? What should be the proper notation in C++? The end result should be all the arrays to be initialized with ***(0,0,"unknown")***.

Comment: `int arr[100] = {0};` only explicitly initializes the ***first*** value in the array to 0, and the only reason that the remaining 99 happen to be 0 is because of default zero-initialization. Use "{1}" instead of "{0}", and you'll be surprised at the results. Having said that, there is no way initialize a custom structure this way directly, in this fashion. A different approach will need to be used.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I'm trying to make sense of the docs (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization), and I can't understand this part (from "Initialization from brace-enclosed lists" section): `and each subsequent initializer without a designator (since C99)initializes the array element at index one greater than the one initialized by the previous initializer.` Can you please explain it?

Comment: It means, simply, each value in a braced initialization list initializes the next element in the array.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik First part of your comment Is correct, I just checked it and you are right that never works with {1}. Second part of your comment is not correct, there is already an answer to this.

Comment: @ikis My answer doesn't contradict what Sam wrote if that's what you are referering to? I just circumvented the problem.

Comment: @ikis, does it necessarily have to be an array? You can initialize vector without problems:     `vector<Node> nodes(100, Node(0, 0, "unknown"));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see what you are saying. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values for your members should help:

```
struct Node
{
    long long data;
    int count;
    std::string name;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(long long data = 0, int count = 0, std::string name = "unknown") :
        data(data),
        count(count),
        name(name),
        left(nullptr),
        right(nullptr)
    {}
};
```

You can then construct arrays without specifying the values:

```
Node nodes[100];
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> int arr[100] = {0};
> ```

What you do here is you initialise the first element with 0, and value initialise the rest. Value initialisation of int is zero initialisation, and this is well-formed.

> ```
> Node nodes[100] = {Node(0,0,"unknown")};
> ```

What you do here is you initialise the first element with `Node(0,0,"unknown")` and value initialise the rest. Value initialisation of a class type invokes a default constructor. `Node` is not default-constructible, so the program is ill-formed.

> ```
> Node nodes[100](Node(0,0,"unknown"));
> ```

You must use brace-initialisation with arrays. Using parentheses is a syntax error.

> ```
> Node nodes[100]{Node(0,0,"unknown")};
> ```

This is same as the first, except direct-initialisation syntax, rather than copy-list-initialisation.

---

Possible solutions:

- Make the class default-initialisable by declaring a default constructor. This can either be a constructor that takes no parameters, or a constructor whose all parameters have defaults.
- Provide an initialiser for every one of the elements of the array (can be a bit tedious for an array of 100 elements).

Comment: I have already updated my question before you posted this.  I removed the int array {0} part.